# ggplot2 dotplot adding scale_shape_manual() not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shapes, dot

I have successfully made a dotplot in R using ggplot2 using this code.

```
data <- data.frame("State" = c("NJ", "NY", "PA", "ND","NJ", "NY", "PA", "ND"), "Year" = c("1985", 
"1985", "1985", "1985", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990"), "DataValue" = c(33, 20, 44, 21, 55, 11, 17, 
46))


p <- ggplot(data,aes(x = State, y = DataValue, color = Year)) + 
  geom_point(data = subset(data, !is.na(DataValue))) + 
  geom_point(data = subset(data, is.na(DataValue)), color = "pink") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(4, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("cyan", "blueviolet", "purple", "turquiose4"))  + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(3.5)) + labs(title = "DataValues", x = "State/Territory", y = "Value") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "grey24")
p<- p + theme(legend.position="bottom")
p
```

I added the shape_scale_manual to change the shape depending on the year and it is not working.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: You may use one of either shape, size or color to identify a group but not multiple. The ggplot2 logic is that if you ex. use color for Variable 1 then you have a legend that explains what each color corresponds to while keeping the shape constant and then if you ex. use shape for Variable 2 then you may add another legend that explains what each shape corresponds to while keeping the color constant.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this what you are looking for:

1. To make scale_shape_manual work you have to map a variable on shape, i.e. map `Year` on `shape`.
2. If you are using different datasets and or aesthetics for the geoms in my opinion it's best to make them local instead of setting them globally in `ggplot()`, i.e. move the mapping on `color` and `shape` into the first `geom_point`. This should give you the right colors and shapes.

```r
data <- data.frame("State" = c("NJ", "NY", "PA", "ND","NJ", "NY", "PA", "ND"), "Year" = c("1985", 
                                                                                          "1985", "1985", "1985", "1990", "1990", "1990", "1990"), "DataValue" = c(33, 20, 44, 21, 55, 11, 17, 
                                                                                                                                                                   46))


library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = State, y = DataValue)) + 
  geom_point(data = subset(data, !is.na(DataValue)), aes(color = Year, shape = Year)) + 
  geom_point(data = subset(data, is.na(DataValue)), color = "pink") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(4, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("cyan", "blueviolet", "purple", "turquiose4"))  + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(3.5)) + labs(title = "DataValues", x = "State/Territory", y = "Value") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "grey24")
p<- p + theme(legend.position="bottom")
p
```

[image]